# Python 3.7- Input only takes integer, no matter how basic the code

Tags: python-3.x, string, input

7 and I can't seem to get input to work for anything other than numbers

```
x = input("Hello" )
```

Just this gives me an error if i input anything other than a number, even floats work but if i put a letter it gives me back NameError: name "X" is not defined. Please help im so confused!

Comment: You are probably using Python 2.x instead of Python 3.7 by accident. try `import sys` followed by `print(sys.version)` to verify the running version.

Comment: Yes, as wrote @uneven_mark, this error is probably problem for Python 2.x. There is another syntax for Python 2.x: `x = raw_input("Your input:")` and the result will string. So if you want to get a number, use the conversion: `x = int(raw_input("Your input:"))`